# Calling function 'InMemoryWebApiModule', function calls are not supported in angular2

Tags: angular

I am making a angular2 tutorial with cli.

When I made HTTP service(tutorial step 7), I discovered one issue.

After try ng serve:

```
Calling function 'InMomoryWebApiModule', function calls are not supported.
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic }           from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode }                   from '@angular/core';
import { environment }                      from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule }                        from './app/app.module';
import{InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA }  from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api'

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule }     from './app-routing.module';

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppComponent }        from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent }  from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent }     from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService }         from './hero.service';
import { HeroSearchComponent } from './hero-search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

in-memory-data.service.ts:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let heroes = [
      {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
      {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
      {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
      {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
      {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
      {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
      {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
      {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
      {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
      {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'}
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: could you include the code where you call  'InMomoryWebApiModule'

Comment: How can i edit my Question?

Comment: At the bottom of your question below the tag `angular2` there should be a few options such as `share` `edit` and `delete`. If you click `edit` it will take you to the editing screen where you can make any changes you need.

Comment: Yes I did it. please look at my code.

Comment: How does your `InMemoryWebApiModule` look like?

Comment: I think he's using this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-in-memory-web-api

Comment: When i comment out this code "import { HeroSearchComponent } from './hero-search.component' " in app.module.ts , and save this file, and when i Uncommented this code, It works normally.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an old version of https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api.

Install npm install --save angular-in-memory-web-api instead (without the 2), that version should be ok. The old version wasn't statically analyzable which caused problems with AoT.